# What regular expression finds four digits before and after an "x"?

Tags: regex

What would be a regular expression to find the four digits in front of and after the "x" in the following strings:

```
234a2343x2834o234 --> 2343, 2834
iur3333x44445555 --> 3333, 4444
owier3423x23sd --> 3423, no match
```

Comment: What regex flavor or programming language?

Comment: In what language?  Regular expressions differ in implementation between languages.

Answer (score 6):

Using Perl regex:

```
/(\d{4})?x(\d{4})?/
```

Note the capture groups and `?` for each 4-digit number. You didn't specify, but if the number at the left side is mandatory, drop the first `?`.

Comment: Note that if the first four digits will always be there (as in the three cases above), you don't need the first `?`.

Answer (score 0):

`(\d{4})x(\d{4})?` would work for Perl compatible regular expressions.

Comment: hm, I seem to have missed your last question mark.  Nevermind, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9]{4})?x([0-9]{4})?
```

See on rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/PhsyDdc1ad

This will return the four digits before and after the first `x`. If there are fewer than 4 digits, as in your third example, there will be an empty group but the regex will still match to potentially return the digits on the other side of `x`.

Note that some regular expression engines define the character group `\d` to contain the digits 0, 1, ..., 9. If you're using one of them you can condense the expression to:

```
(\d{4})?x(\d{4})?
```